# 2D Group Collision Detection

Tags: c++, collision-detection

I'm trying to implement collision detection in my game, but what seemed easy at first has mutated into a monster I can't quite tackle without some help.

The game will be an RTS at some point, but right now it's only a bunch of units which can be told to move to a particular location on the screen. But, the units keep disappearing into only one unit, so I defined bounding boxes for each unit and tested for collision between the units after moving them in the game loop so as to separate them.

That didn't work because I had not implemented a way of knowing that the particular unit I am shifting does not take some other unit's place (which I had already iterated through).

I tried to maintain positions (or regions) already occupied so as to shift where there are no units. But this also does not work in some cases, such as when a unit is shifted in any of the four corners of the screen, it can't go beyond the screen's bounds and also cannot occupy the regions occupied the units it is colliding with.

I'm still pretty sure I'm overly complicating something which can be done easily with a different approach.

Each unit has it's own bounding sphere, position, direction vector and velocity vector.

```
class Unit {
    friend class Party;
    protected:
        float xPos, yPos;
        float destX, destY;
        float detectionRange;
        Vector *vel;
        Vector *dest;

        int dir;
        int offset;
        int width, height;

        Circle *circle;                 //Bounding Circle
        ...
    public:
        ...
};

//Collision Checking
void Party::checkCollisions() {
    bool noCol;
    float dx, dy;
    Circle *mCircle = NULL;
    Circle *sCircle = NULL;

    do {
        noCol = true;
        for(int i=0; i<numUnits; i++) {
            mCircle = units[i]->getCircle();
            for(int j=0; j<numUnits; j++) {
                if(j==i) {
                    continue;
                }

                sCircle = units[j]->getCircle();
                if(mCircle->isColliding(sCircle)) {
                    noCol = false;
                   mCircle->getShifts(sCircle, &dx, &dy);
                   units[i]->shift(dx, dy);
                   units[j]->shift(-dx, -dy);
                }
            }
        }
    } while(noCol == false);
}

//IsColliding. This is overriden for isColliding(Circle *circle), but here
//you see the actual algorithm.
bool Circle::isColliding(float X, float Y, int rad) {
    float mag = sqrt((X-x)*(X-x) + (Y-y)*(Y-y));

    if(mag <= (radius + rad)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

//Get Shifts
void Circle::getShifts(Circle *c, float *dx, float *dy) {
    float x1 = x - c->x;
    float y1 = y - c->y;

    if(x1 > -1 && x1 < 1) {
        x1 = 1;
    }

    if(y1 > -1 && y1 < 1) {
        y1 = 1;
    }

    *dx = x1/fabs(x1);
    *dy = y1/fabs(y1);
}
```

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAzbMkAsDBU&feature=youtu.be) shows what I have got so far, but it's apparent that it is extremely glitched and has unnecessary unit movements.

What I want is that when two or more units come together, they flock naturally. But all units will not form one flock at all times. Since each unit has a different detection range, it is possible to separate one or more units from a flock. I want this so that later I can select and move different groups of units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For every unit store a location where this unit wants to be.
2. Keep moving the unit into to that location.
3. For *ALL* units (you process ALL units in this step): When collision occurs, push the unit away from the collision, by a **SMALL** distance. i.e. if you need to move unit by (x:10.0; y:10.0) to avoid collision, move it by (x:1.0; y:1.0) instead. When two units collide you can push them both away from point of collision at once, but keep step small, even if it doesn't immediately resolve collision.
4. Repeat #3 N times (N should be around 10..50) or until no collision occurs for any unit.

This is a dumb approach that will automatically handle all your problems. This algorithm is also useful when you have many object placed on same spot and you want to move them away to some reasonable positions where they no longer collide.

Alternatively you could study [boids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids). Java demo is available [here](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/applet/). This would handle unit collision/formation without abusing collision detection.

---

```
struct Vec2{
    float x;
    float y;
    Vec2(){
    }
    Vec2(float x_, float y_)
    :x(x_), y(y_){
    }
    Vec2(const Vec2& other)
    :x(other.x), y(other.y){
    }
    Vec2& operator*=(const float f){
        x *= f; y *= f;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Circle{
    Vec2 pos; 
    float radius;
};

float dot(const Vec2& arg1, const Vec2& arg2){
    return arg1.x*arg2.x + arg1.y*arg2.y;
}

float length(const Vec2& arg){
   return sqrtf(dot(arg, arg));
}

Vec2 operator-(const Vec2& arg1, const Vec2& arg2){
   return Vec2(arg1.x - arg2.x, arg1.y - arg2.y);
}

Vec2 scale(const Vec2& arg, const float scale){
   return Vec2(arg.x*scale, arg.y*scale);
}

bool collide(const Circle& c1, const Circle& c2){
    Vec2 diff = c1.pos - c2.pos;
    float maxSquareDistance = c1.radius+c2.radius;
    maxSquareDistance *= maxSquareDistance;
    return (dot(diff, diff) < maxSquareDistance);
}

Vec getShiftVector(const Circle& c1, const Circle& c2){
    diff = c2.pos - c1.pos;
    maxSquareDistance = c1.radius + c2.radius;
    maxSquareDistance *= maxSquareDistance;
    float squareDistance = dot(diff, diff);
    if (squareDistance > maxSquareDistance)
       return Vec2(0, 0);

    float distance = sqrtf(squareDistance)
    if (distance){
        diff.x /= distance;
        diff.y /= distance;
    }
    else{
        diff = Vec2(1, 0);
    }

    float scaleFactor = c1.radius + c2.radius - distance;

    diff.x *= scaleFactor;
    diff.y *= scaleFactor;

    return diff;        
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out, thanks for your answer and the link. Is there any way of being sure, once I have made sure one particular unit is not involved in any collisions, that I do not push another unit onto the first unit? For example, I'm iterating through my list of units while considering a main unit with which I check collisions. I move the main unit after checking collision with the first iteration. I find it to be colliding with the second unit in the sequence as well, and I move it such that it is again at the location of the first unit I checked. What method do I deploy to avoid this?

Comment: @Rikonator: Step #3 is applied to all units. You push all units away (by **small** distance) from collision in this step, and then repeat it until no units collide with anything, or until you run out of steps. If you run out of steps, this means you're trying to stuff large number of units into very small space. There was a scientific name for this method but I forgot it. I think it was related to IK solvers - incremental solver or something. Another thing you should keep in mind that using this method units might exceed their maximum speed (if they have it) in certain circumstances.

Comment: @Rikonator: "What method do I deploy to avoid this?" This method already deals with this problem. Just process ALL units in step #3, push them ALL from their immediate collision by *small* distance even if this doesn't immediately resolve collision, then repeat the whole process 50 times or until there is no collision. Works wonderfully when your units use bounding spheres for collision detection. With boxes results could be worse.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm pretty sure with your steps and after studying a bit about boids I can make it work. This will also help me later on, when I add obstacles and upgrade the units to work on path finding.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you again, but my application of your algorithm does not seem to work. There are too many collisions and shifting, even when I repeat step #3 until a flag which is true only if there are no collisions becomes true. I probably should study more about flocking for this particular problem. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: @Rikonator: I can't give you advice withotu seeing the code. The algorithm in question worked well for me in the past for making dungeon crawler prototype. You mentioned that you used bounding boxes. Try using bounding spheres instead - for this algorithm spheres are better candidates because it is easier to select movement vector that pushes two objects away from each other. Movement vector is important in this case.

Comment: I did use bounding spheres, well circles, with your algorithm. I'll post the code I used in my question.

Comment: @Rikonator: Your "get shifts" code does not take circle radius into account. It is broken.

Comment: @Rikonator: Anyway... if you're still having trouble either grab pen/paper and figure out how math works or hire somebody else to do the work for you. You have to try solving the problem yourself, without asking for help - this way you'll learn faster.

Comment: Yes, I was simply considering shifting because it was to be a unit shift away from the collision. I should have used vectors to get the unit shift vector.

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply a direction vector to every unit and have them head towards that vector relatively? For example, if you generate vector that points 45 degrees northeast and is 30 meters away from your group's current location (the current location should be either the location average of the entire group or by some scheme such as one that concerns the closest unit) just move each unit, relative to it's own position, to that location. Now, you should have a collision system setup in order to allow you to handle something such as an enemy unit charging through your group or your group coming into contact with some stationary object. Now , as for your corner collision problem, you should add an extra collision check to make sure that the unit the colliding unit is touching is able to relocate itself (i.e. he's not surrounded on all 4 sides) if you want to have the touching unit push the touched unit. Otherwise you could just have your touching unit simply stop in place.

You could use this as a reference: http://www.gamespp.com/algorithms/collisiondetection/

Comment: I already have direction vectors for each unit. I should have mentioned this in my question, but the units are separate entities, only when two or more are directed to the same point should they cluster like a group or swarm. I'll add some code to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It sort of sounds like your collision code is off. What are your bounding volumes, boxes? Rotated boxes?

Try using Circles for the units bounding volume. Most games use circle on units since it's cheaper and accurate. Plus the circle->circle collision code is pretty cheap.

If all units are told to move to a specific location, they should keep pushing into other units and not move inside eachother. I can picture some wierd situaions happening with large groups, like units popping through others, but deal with that later.

Just make sure that once a unit is colliding with an object, the code "pushes" that units position back out. Or, push it back by its direction * speed.

Comment: I'm currently working with rectangular boxes. Once I'm able to get the collision to actually work, I'll shift to better collision detection methods. My problem here is knowing how to shift the colliding units. I'm currently iterating through the list of units, and I think here lies the problem. I need a better data structure or a better way of checking which units are colliding.